# IE 11 - Session is reset to null

Tags: internet-explorer, session, internet-explorer-11, session-cookies, aem

We have intermittent issues in AEM web application that session is set to null.
We are using AEM application to call a third party web service using session. We have Saml authentication to handle the Login part. This issue is happening only for particular users and it is intermittent.
   Is this the IE-11 known bug/ is there any workaround for this? This issue is not reproducible in any of the other browsers

Comment: Could you add more information about the issue? You mentioned it is intermittent, so it intermittent on IE as well? Which version of aem are you using? Are you using csrf protection?

Comment: Yes it is intermittent on IE and we are using AEM 6.0. Yes we are using CSRF protection, but not using the out of box framework.